# Don't include label in ng-options

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've got an ng-options multiselect list that I'm trying to append some icons before the option text with a `::before` class. This works great in chrome but not Firefox.  The content on the `::before` seems to wipe out the option text.

```css
.optionClass:before{
    content:"::before "
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option class="optionClass">first</option>
    <option class="optionClass" label="sec" >second</option>
</select>
```

I'm expecting to see both "first" and "second", but in FF I can only see first. The text for "second" is hidden.

Once again, this works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Is there a way around this issue with just css?  If not, is there a way I can leave the label elements off the options when using ng-options with AngularJs 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

I found a tenuous workaround for this issue.

I created a FF bug report for this issue.  One of the dev's said "This is kind of expected" but then he referenced using attr(label) appended to the content.  This doesnt work for a number of reasons in the `:before` content (in my case because I'm display FA icons in that field) so I appended it to the `:after`

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1644611

The workaround is to create a css Firefox selector and then append the label to the 
`:after` content field using `attr(label)`  Hopefully this doesnt result in any false positives that would display the label twice.  In the limited cases I've tested so far it seems to be holding up.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .optionClass:after{
        content: attr(label);
    }
}
```